# How to align divs inside parent div and fill it

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I use bootstrap, and I'd like to align the three div inside a parent without any border:

```
  <div id="parent" class="col-lg-12">
      <div id="main"> ... </div>
      <div id="leftside"> ... </div>
      <div id="bottom"> ... </div>
  </div>
```

**div #bottom:** fill the bottom of the parent div from left to right with height: 100px

**div #leftside:** fill the left side from top to div#bottom with 100px

**div #main:** fill the rest of parent div

**UPDATE:**
My question wasn't accurate enough.
I'd like something like this: 
[jsfiddle.net/kvs72e2j](http://jsfiddle.net/kvs72e2j)
but without the fixed property. I'd like the divs to fill parent, and parent must fill it's superparent, but not the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html:

```
<div id="parent" class="col-lg-12">
<div id="top">
  <div id="leftside"> ... </div>
  <div id="main"> ... </div>
</div>
  <div id="bottom"> ... </div>
```

css:

```
#parent {
    position: relative;
    background-color: black;
}

#top {
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

#leftside {
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}

#main {
    background-color: blue;
}

#bottom {
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I just realized that I made it unnecessarily complicated.  Here is a simpler solution:
html:

```
  <div id="parent" class="col-lg-12">
    <div id="leftside"> ... </div>
      <div id="main"> ... </div>
      <div id="bottom"> ... </div>
  </div>
```

css:

```
#parent {
    background-color: black;
}

#leftside {
    float: left;
    min-width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}

#main {
    background-color: blue;
}

#bottom {
    clear: both;
    background-color: green;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately I still haven't solved my problem. I'd like to get something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/kvs72e2j but in this solution divs are fixed. I need them to fill the parent. And parent must fill it's parent..